# Any recommendations for starter tutorials for Titanium Mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium

I'm just starting to code in Javascript and in Titanium. Does anyone out there have recommendations for **starter tutorials**? Would prefer tutorials that are somewhat step-by-step and actually describe stuff instead of just throwing a huge chunk of code with no explanations; like being thrown into Kitchensink without any explanations; since debugging is difficult to implement in Titanium.

I'm also gonna recommend some tutorials that I've found useful so far:

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX_7NGvcNk4
2. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-build-a-pizza-ordering-app/
3. http://www.jonathanspies.com/posts/18-How-to-make-a-Native-App-Form-that-doesn-t-suck-with-Titanium
4. http://agiliq.com/blog/2011/02/iphoneandroid-application-development-using-titani/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love this tutorial. It starts from the very basic and discusses quite a lot of modules:

http://cssgallery.info/seven-days-with-titanium-day-0-introduction/

Edit 2018, 7 years after originally writing this answer.

There are tons of guides now, a LOT of them on the official documentation: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide

Also the alloy kitchensink is a great go-to https://github.com/appcelerator/kitchensink-v2

Answer (score 1):

It is better to explore the **KitchenSink** example that is provided by Titanium Appcelerator team itself! here is the link to [download](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) the latest version for the same. All the best. :)

Comment: The problem is, I can't compile it and run in Android. Got it fresh from github but it isnt working :(

Answer (score 0):

You can start from [The Wiki for Titanium](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Titanium+Mobile) .

Answer (score 0):

I will give a +1 to the Kitchen Sink example but don't use it as a best practices on how to structure your app.  There are a lot of examples of how to use the api and learn about the different options but the way they structure the project is just bad practice.

For project structure take a look at tweetanium and struct.

- http://blog.krawaller.se/titanium-application-structure-learning-from
- https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium

Finally, check out Appcelerator on Vimeo

- http://vimeo.com/appcelerator